# How to compress output video with trim using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Need to know how to compress output video using FFMPEG along with trim command.

***Command to trim video***

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -t 44.1 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -t 27.3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

My input.mp4 video is 4GB with high resoultion and output video is also of high quality with large size. Is it possible, to reduce size of output video?

Comment: Your output is already compressed. I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do. Describe the problem you are trying to solve and I can provide a more appropriate answer that you can copy and paste.

Comment: @llogan check updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `-crf` & `-preset`

You are outputting MP4. Default encoder is libx264 (most builds of `ffmpeg` have `--enable-libx264` so I'll assume yours does too).

1. Control quality with `-crf`. Range is 0-31. Default is 23. Lossless is 0 (huge files). Visually lossless is 17 or 18. A higher value is a lower quality and therefore a lower file size. Use the highest value that still provides an acceptable quality. Increasing the CRF value by +6 will result in about 50% smaller output size (such as `-crf 23` vs `-crf 29`, not comparing input vs output sizes). The output file size cannot be predicted using `-crf`.
2. Use `-preset` to control compression efficiency and therefore encoding speed. A slower preset: enables more fancy and complicated compression features, takes longer to encode, and usually provides a smaller file size. Use the slowest preset you can. Default is *medium*.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -t 44.1 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -t 27.3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 29 -preset slower output.mp4
```

## Even smaller files with libx265

Add `-c:v libx265` to output HEVC/H.265 video instead of H.264. It is a slower encoder but will usually output a smaller file size for the same quality. This format may not be supported by your player/device.

libx265 also uses `-crf` and `-preset`, but the `-crf` values are somewhat different.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -t 44.1 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -t 27.3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx265 -crf 35 -preset slow output.mp4
```

## If you need to target a specific output file size

Use [two-passes](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass). Otherwise, just use `-crf`.

## Don't use `-fs`

`-fs` is supposed to stop encoding when the output reaches a certain size. It does not automatically fit the complete video to fit a specified size. Also, `-fs` may not be accurate anyway. See [Limit file size in FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59053459/) for more info about `-fs`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Need to know how to accelerate the video? If my video length is 21 minutes, i want to make it fast and run in 2 minutes

Comment: @puneet18 Should be asked as a new, standalone question (but search first: it's probably already been answered several times).

Comment: ok will add as another question. I tried -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" but no success. Will search and try more. Thanks

Comment: @puneet18 You can ask a question about it if you can't figure it out.

Comment: check https://superuser.com/questions/1583090/how-to-accelerate-the-video-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the file size with `-fs` and then specify your desired file size in bytes.

Of course, make it a reasonable size, not so small that your media is unwatchable. Using `-vcodec h265` could also help as the H.265 codec allows for smaller file sizes and it is newer.

You should also add a `-crf` value - change this to something around 26-30. Higher `crf` value means lower bitrate, and as such, lower `crf` values correspond the higher bitrates, so adjust this as you will.

To use `-vcodec` in the way I have described above you would add `-vcodec libx265`.

To use `-fs`, if, for example you wanted to limit your file size to 250mb, you would add `-fs 250000000`
You must convert the file size from megabytes (or gigabytes, depending on what you want) to bytes. You can do this by just searching "mb to bytes" or "gb to bytes" in google.

If you wanted your `-crf` value to be 28, you would type `-crf 28` and you can adjust that number as you desire.

I suggest playing around with the `-fs` and `-crf` limit until you get a file size and video quality you're happy with.

So, assuming the trim command you added above in your question works, your final command should look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -t 44.1 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -t 27.3 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libx265 -fs YOUR_FILE_SIZE_IN_BYTES -crf 29 output.mp4
```

Remember you must specify your desired file size in bytes if you want to use this method, and you can also change the `-crf` value.

Comment: can I use compressed command with trim as well ?

Comment: Of course, just as long as you correctly add the new values

Comment: can you please add commands as how to use -fs, -vcodec & -crf? Also, I've videos with & without audio, so is the command same  ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some examples. And yes, it will work whether the video has audio or not.

Comment: Please do not recommend the use of the fs parameter, see llogan's answer.