# How to accelerate the video using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I used following command to trim & compress video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -to 867.3 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -to 1101.4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0[v]" -map "[v]" -crf 29 output.mp4
```

Need to know what parameters to pass for accelerate the video? For eg, if my video length is 20 minutes, I want it to make it 2 minute.

I tried to pass `-vf "setpts=0.1*PTS"` on above command but it's not working.

Video accelerate command is as follow which is working properly:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.1*PTS[v]" -map "[v]"  output.mp4
```

But I want to accelerate video with trim & compress command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `-vf` and `-filter_complex`. Do all filtering in your `-filter_complex`:

```
ffmpeg -ss 823.2 -to 867.3 -i input.mp4 -ss 1074.1 -to 1101.4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,setpts=0.1*PTS[v]" -map "[v]" -crf 29 output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html).

Comment: Working properly. Thanks! I don't know much configurations of ffmpeg but now I know lots of commands. Thanks for your help & support.